# Print comprehension list as string

Tags: python, list, loops

Suppose I have a comprehension list:

```
list1 = [("hello","my name"),("is","hayhay")]
```

How would I print this out using a loop? I tried doing

```
for line in list1:
   print(line);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a list of tuples, which are also iterators. So for every element (i.e. for every "`line`", you need to iterate through that tuple to print out the elements. A nested for loop, in other words.

Comment: Just an FYI, there's no comprehension in this code. That's just called a list.

Comment: please show us your expected result. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want them joined as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print each tuple:

```
for i in list1:
    print(i)

('hello', 'my name')
('is', 'hayhay')
```

If you want to print as a series of strings:

```
for i in list1:
    for l in i:
        print(l)

hello
my name
is
hayhay
```

If you want to print as a unified string:

```
list2 = ""
for i in list1:
    for l in i:
        list2 += l+" "
print(list2)

hello my name is hayhay
```

Comment: @Hay Hay Bun Bun If this answered your question - great! (mark as answered so people know you've found your solution). Otherwise, please show your expected output. :)

Comment: sorry, it said I had to wait like ten minutes or something, thank you again! you are so helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
list1 = [("hello","my name"),("is","hayhay")]

str='' 
for key,item in dict(list1).items(): 
  str+=key + " " + item + " " 
print(str[:-1]) 

# hello my name is hayhay
```

Comment: @hay hay bun bun - this is the next iteration I was about to post. Great answer if you're trying to create a single unified string.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't end lines have ";" 
You need to unpack the tuple to be able to print the string inside of it, if that's what you trying to achieve

```
list1 = [("hello","my name"),("is","hayhay")]
for line in list1:
    print(*line)
```

Comment: downvoting the answer without even adding enough info to solve the issue, where's the output you expect. Anyways I edited the code, this should work! You trying to unpack the tuple

Comment: The answer was incorrect based on what? How did you determine that? I there's no output to be compared with in the first place

Comment: I meant you don't need ; to end each line there for I removed it, second, they didn't specify output to see what exactly they need so I made the best judgment and assumed they're beginners with python and probably having a syntax issue. Don't be quick at judging I'm trynna help not much!

Comment: **And the code they have would actually run without the semicolon! **

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be the most efficient but does the job.

Please see below.

Thanks,

```
list1 = [("hello","my name"), ("is", "hayhay")];
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[0])):
        print(list1[i][j]);
```